# Navigating and addressing QMLComponents

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on a desktop application the uses a QML GUI with a lot of QML Components.
These are parts of the hierarchy:

```
main -> toolbar -> searchbar -> editfield
```

and

```
main -> resultlist -> header -> button1
```

I could not find a way to access the text contents of editfield in a signal handler for button1. Is it possible to do that in QML or Javascript?

I know I can access the element in the C++ part by using the objectName property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to QML uses dynamic scoping ([→ Doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativescope.html#component-instance-hierarchy)), child elements can access the properties of all ancestors
and it doesn't matter if they are in different files.

So you could add an `editFieldText` property to main and bind the
`text` property of editfield to it. Then you can access `editFieldText`
from everywhere:

```
//=== main.qml ===
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: main

    property string editFieldText

    Toolbar {
        // [...]
    }

    Resultlist {
        // [...]
    }
}


//=== EditField.qml ===
import QtQuick 1.0

TextInput {
    // bind text property to main.editFieldText
    Binding {
        target: main;
        property: "editFieldText";
        value: text
    }
}


//=== Header.qml ===
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    Button {
        onClick: {
            console.log(main.editFieldText);
            // or simply
            console.log(editFieldText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add an id to the TextInput component ("myid") and then use "value: myid.text" in the Binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias properties to have the editfield.text as a property of main. This property should be accessible from button1.

Comment: I tried this but failed because afaik you can only alias properties one level below the current Components.

Comment: This solution works if you go from the innermost scope to to top level scope and propagate the property one level up in every case.